# GSON Minimum Java version required

Tags: java, gson

What is the minimum version of Java/JDK required to use GSON API?
And for gson-2.2.1.jar ?

Comment: Have you tried searching for an answer?

Comment: Yes, JSON.simple seems to be the answer to use GSON for JDK1.4 and below
http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/

Answer (score 4):

Gson uses JDK 1.5 features heavily; that's the minimum version for Gson, specifically annotations and generics.

Check out this piece of GSON source code, where annotations are used

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface SerializedName {
    String value();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I was facing some issues related with this, the latest version of GSon at the time is 2.8.5 this doesn't work with java 1.5(Minimun 1.6).

The last version of GSon compatible with Java 1.5 is GSon 2.4

Comment: Confirmed! Gson 2.4 is the last compatible version with Java 1.5. 
Details here: https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Answer (score 2):

You need to have minimum of Java 1.5 because it uses java 1.5 features heavily like annotations.

Answer (score 2):

I can not find any "compatibility table" between Gson versions and JAVA versions. Is there any? I use Gson 2.8.5 and do not know if it is fully compatible with JAVA 1.7.

Answer (score 0):

`Gson` uses generics, so you need to be using `JDK 1.5+` while working with it.

Having said that, I don't see why you will not be using `JDK 6` at least.

Comment: We have an application that uses JDK1.4 and is calling a Restful service - that returns a response as json, I have to process the json string

Comment: Ok, JDK 1.4 is very old and you could backport some of the required JDK 1.5 classes to 1.4, but that's risky and 1.5+ is worth the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

With jdk1.8 till gson 2.8.5 works fine.  Later version till 2.10.1  are compiled fine but failed in deploying the application in jboss server with invalid constant type: 19