# Which GSON version for Java 1.4

Tags: java, json, gson

Is there any location where the JDK version supporting that GSON version is documented?

Specifically I want to know the highest GSON version that will run with Java 1.4.

I have a embedded JVM with version 1.4 that I cannot upgrade, and I want to test if GSON works on it.

GSON versions are available for download at this [link](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/list?can=1&q=&colspec=Filename%20Summary%20Uploaded%20ReleaseDate%20Size%20DownloadCount).

Comment: Seems to have been answered (1.5) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13992294/gson-minimum-java-version-required

Comment: I got that post on Google and read that! But, that post says to use JDK 1.5. But, I can't change the JDK version. I want to know which GSON version works with JDK 1.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it looks like GSON does not work with JDK 1.4. The answer provided by @Steven specifically states that GSON heavily uses features of JDK 1.5. Also, if you look at the oldest available GSON version in Maven Central (version 1.1), the `pom.xml` indicates that the minimum version for JDK is 1.5. [Source](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/1.1/gson-1.1.pom), search for "targetJdk" and you'll see 1.5 listed.

Unfortunately this means GSON won't work with JDK 1.4.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can run it with 1.4, even the Gson 1.0.1 is compiled for 1.5

You can check that, too:

- download the jar you want to check
- open a class-file inside
- look for the bytes 6 and 7
- compare result with this table https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file#General_layout